# Running test in Visual Studio gives Excel errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, excel-interop

I am using C# with Selenium for my tests, and Excel Interop for reporting test results.

When I run my test in Visual Studio, it shows the following error:

[image]

Clicking on Debug, opens the Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger, and when I debug, I get the following messages:

When unhandled exception at 0x7c812afb in excel.exe: 0xe0000002: 0xe0000002.

An unhandled win32 exception occurred in excel.exe[3920].

Has anyone experienced such error? Can anyone suggest me anything to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Event Viewer shows:
Faulting application excel.exe, version 12.0.6545.5000, stamp 4c654035, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 5.1.2600.6055, stamp 4d00f27d, debug? 0, fault address 0x00019af2.

Comment: Can you give more info? Did you test it on another machine? Which version of the Interop are you using? Did you step through your code and see where it throws the error? Did you look in the event log?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check out of the problem is not ntdll.dll? A quick seach on google gave me this page:
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/ntdlldll.htm